# Function to write to file works in .cpp file, but not in .h file

Tags: c, text, file-io

I need to write and read some text on a `.txt` file, using `fprintf`, `fscanf` and `fopen` as main functions.

I gathered them all in a single void function in a single header file. This function should read and write on a `txt` file.

This is the code:

```
void scrivi_valori(int variabili[], int num_variabili, int controlloprimocaso){
    FILE * testo;
    testo = fopen ("risultati.txt","w+");
    if(controlloprimocaso==0){
        fprintf(testo, "%d-", 1);
        for(i=0;i<num_variabili;i++){
            fprintf(testo, "%d.", variabili[i]);
        }
        fprintf(testo, "-%d\n", 1);
        fclose(testo);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, `risultati.txt` is totally blank. The real problem is that I moved the code in a `.cpp` file and it worked, `risultati.txt` was written perfectly.

So my question is: why does this function work in a `.cpp` file and it doesn't in a `.h` file?

**Thank you all, but i solved :)
I put all the functions in my headers in one file.h.
Also i open file using the "w" mode and not "w+" mode.
Doing like this the program works perfectly!
Thanks all :)**

Comment: Where are you using `fscanf`?

Comment: this looks like pure C to me

Comment: Do you have any compilation error message? Your code have serious problems.

Comment: God, right about i.

No compilation problem by the way.

Comment: what value do you pass for the `controlloprimocaso` variable?  You have to pass it a 0 to print anything. Do you pass it 0?

Answer (score 0):

It may be foolish but, are you sure that you've included a.h in your code?
I mean do you have:
    #include "a.h"
in your .cpp code where you use it or not?
since its working perfectly for me at least.

this works for me:
.cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "header.h"

main()
{
    int test[2];
    test[0]= 3;
    test[1]=6;
    scrivi_valori(test,2,0);
    return 0;
}
```

and header.h file

```
void scrivi_valori(int variabili[], int num_variabili, int controlloprimocaso)
{
    FILE * testo;
    testo = fopen ("risultati.txt","w+");
    if(controlloprimocaso==0)
   {
        fprintf(testo, "%d-", 1);
        for(int i=0;i<num_variabili;i++)
        {
            fprintf(testo, "%d.", variabili[i]);
        }
        fprintf(testo, "-%d\n", 1);
        fclose(testo);
    }
}
```

notice that i need to be declared

Comment: If i do like you say, it tells me that i'm redefining scrivi_valori function.

Comment: you use g++ for compile?

Comment: please copy and paste my code and give the same name to your .h file and compile using normal g++. and if you encounter error copy the error here. It should work perfectly

Comment: It works perfectly, but my compiler redifines scrivi_valori function

Comment: finally its working or not? ant the approach suggested by macfij is the right way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

your approach is wrong. in header files you should store only declarations of functions, source files are the place where function is defined. so, your header file should like:

```
// your_func.h
void scrivi_valori(int variabili[], int num_variabili, int controlloprimocaso);
```

and source file:

```
// your_func.cpp
#include "your_hunc.h"
void scrivi_valori(int variabili[], int num_variabili, int controlloprimocaso)
{
    FILE * testo;
    testo = fopen ("risultati.txt","w+");
    if(controlloprimocaso==0)
    {
        fprintf(testo, "%d-", 1);
        for(int i=0;i<num_variabili;i++)
        {
            fprintf(testo, "%d.", variabili[i]);
        }
        fprintf(testo, "-%d\n", 1);
        fclose(testo);
    }
}
```

and then, if you need to use a `scrivi_valori()` function in other cpp file, you just include a header file and a preprocessor will paste your function definition onto file where you are including that header file.

Comment: I moved all the functions in a single header file, i moved all the declared functions in cpp files, i included only the header in main cpp and... doesn't work. It gives me the error 

"undefined reference to.." all other functions

Comment: you should also include that single header file in all of your cpp files. if the error from ``scrivi_valori()`` went off, try that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write source code of your program in a header file(.h).
You can just write source code in a source file (.cpp).
In C++ there is the extension .hpp. .hpp files can be included like a header but still may contain source code. A .hpp file is like a compromise between a header file and source file.,

Comment: I will try .hpp asap, thank you. What happens if i leave source code in a .h file?

Comment: The source code will not be executed in this case. This is if you already know it is not executed in a header file.